# Typescript is there a way to cast type for case in switch?

Tags: typescript

I have a function that check request data to access api endpoint. For each endpoint there can be different preLoaded data for this specific endpoint.

Problem is that for every operation i need to cast request data to endpoint data type. Is there a way to assert it only one time for case block scope? Or i should take some different approach.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=21&ssc=6&pln=1&pc=1#code/FAAjIFwTwBwUxAJTgRwDwBUQF4QFcA7AawIHsB3AgPhxAG8Q4CATGUgSwIgC4QBnCACdOAcwA0IZgEMIU3hgC%20ocMrDR4IAKIsAjLQHCCI1ZFgJtzAEwB9AMy0CeALYAjOIJMmAxqQICQXgAWcF5EiKQANgi4ABSCqLyEJBQEAJS8LqSRcFIEODR0JuD85OwQQSAxcaggUnxIqKkAdEysHFyp9EXF4F51CADkrWxcOgO8hT1TPewAZlXxKLX1yOgWOlTN0rK0A4HsA53xEHiCeUJ4CCDdU0rTPX18g8O%20EJbjNw-9IEMsIxC2cZde73apLOoNNYsGy2TZNbZSEAAalwOgA3J9QYtlpC0BYYXCESAAFSojEg6ZgnGrPHQuyEmSIgC0ZMx0zmCxqEJp%20PpW0ZtAArEc4CczpBBJcwGywHcKZI4LMpHgIjwQMdTnklREnp85bKgA).

```
type Req<T = unknown> = { endpoint: string, data: T}

type End1 = string
type End2_3 = number

const checkRole = (req: unknown): boolean => {
    switch ((req as Req).endpoint) {
        case 'endpont1': {
            if((req as Req<End1>).data = 'hi') return true  
        }
        case 'endpont2':
        case 'endpont3': {
            (req as Req<End2_3>).data += 1;
            (req as Req<End2_3>).data *= 1;
            (req as Req<End2_3>).data -= 1;
            if((req as Req<End2_3>).data = 5) return true  
        }
        default: return false
    }
}
```

UPD. [Variant that jared suggested](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=27&pc=2#code/MYewdgzgLgBAlhAKjAvDAPIgfACgE4CmAjgFwwCuYA1mCAO5gCUZhR8EMyKWMA3gFAwhMQlHJ4wMKHnIF%20AX36DhUAJ4AHAjABKxTKgrVaDHml4wCYACbqQcMFDLQ89gOYAaGFYCGUb2URFYRhlITVNGABRawBGA2c3UKkNLWirACYAfQBmAzByAFsAIwI8JKTQSFhgAAsCYCptEAAbLTR8YjJKGnomMiKQFoJvSW4%20JOCIOjgoWpgcDrZvDl0iRgA6Sxs7B0Zx4IPhYGWtAHIt2wcY07IBQ-vhOAAzBdYYZZ09NJisDZ8-AynGpwU57UTiSTSWRCCb3IIPI4nGDnayXKDpG6ww7HCBnC7gKDZG77BGHZ7zBCIdCrdBpLLZLC4ViMPZ3UkI1jrf7eGAAajQMQA3Fj2UJOdy%20QLhaKHuLfDz%20TAhSLRXKAYrlTL7uCJFIZFoQlqhPDSSaEVYCE9vORmo4RAQxLqrc1cSLFPIgA).

Comment: You want a [user-defined type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards).

Comment: @JaredSmith so i should chain hungrets of api endpoints in if else?

Comment: The initial check for the switch case is easy, differentiating between the data property types is harder. I'm trying to figure that part out still. You may just want to go with separate types/type guards.

Comment: Question, why is req unknown? You could have `checkRole = <T,>(req: Req<T>): boolean => `

Comment: @JaredSmith i've added a variant with your suggestion, how does it looks?)

Comment: it's just for example, unknown is easier to cast to other type :)

Comment: The way you wrote it is going to destroy the type safety. Correct: you're just doing a more verbose cast.

Comment: *"i need to cast request data to endpoint data type"* -- JavaScript does not support type casting.

Comment: my type is shared between client and server, and i know which one for witch route will be, so it's fine for me i think

Comment: @JaredSmith if you will think of any better alternative, please type the answer, or type your first suggestion so i could accept it.

Comment: `req as Req<End1>` is not type casting. It is called a [*type assertion*](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) and its purpose is to tell the compiler: *"I know what I'm doing, stop bothering me with errors about mismatching types"*.

Comment: @axiac yep, sorry for wrong word.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depeding on the specifics of your use case, you might be interested in [discriminated unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#discriminated-unions):

```
type Req = { endpoint: "endpoint1", data: string }
    | { endpoint: "endpoint3" | "endpoint2", data: number }

const checkRole = (_req: unknown): boolean => {
    let req = _req as Req;
    switch (req.endpoint) {
        case 'endpoint1': {
            if (req.data = 'hi') return true
            return false;
        }
        case 'endpoint3':
        case 'endpoint2': {
            req.data += 1;
            req.data *= 1;
            req.data -= 1;
            if (req.data == 5) return true
        }
        default: return false
    }
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=4&ssc=1&pln=5&pc=48#code/FAFwngDgpgBASlAjjAvDA3jKA7AJhAewEtsQAuGAIh32NIEZKAaGXAQxDYoGcQAnEgHMYAX2AwJMAD4YseQiXJUaC0gGZK05fLogATM1YcuMbAFcAtgCMofUcGABjAtl4xHACyiOA1nAIANrBoABQA+nxIFGbYPtgEAO7YAJQUVgSBUGzYqAB8GOKSQSAwkchoEUgwbNzwSADchRLcCUQgnjAhZQB0KrrJBZJD7jWwAOR9ivRjFOhNw0NEAGadPeycqDBjHkRjA5EgZnw5-GZQ8wsSB0c5S2wB3FCNl-YvjqNbk+ozF5Lvj58dIo9DNBi9JGtjDAANRoejPcFXJDddZsGAAKjhCMRkI2AFosb8FstVsjUag0ABWfZQQ7HGCnc4vMQvXBQO5mAJKa70u4PJmSMQiIA)

Comment: very intresting solution, you can even skip _req part and just use Req instead of unknown

Comment: @RTW yeah, didn't know what you did with `checkRole`  role after so i just kept the original signature type.